# Sybase 12.5 Return Set alternative

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor, sap-ase

While working with a cursor i found myself with a cursor that inserted all the variables of a few tables into a cursor, then the cursor into a temporary table and a select from the table (It had to be done that way since otherwise it would do a memory error)

Trying to improve the performance of the this procedure i tried to eliminate the Temporary table and pull the cursor but i don't know the return set alternative for Sybase 12.5. Does anyone knows a return set exemple for this system or knows a way to improve this performance?

(The table needs to use a cursor since it always breaks from excess of memory usage, also, i can only do a single select in this search with the excepcion of the one to fill the cursor since it will return the select.

For exemple:

```
While (@@sqlstatus = 0)
SELECT @variables from the cursor
```

will not work since it will be a multiples selects.

Answer (score 0):

If you select values in each iteration of the cursor, they will be returned as separate resultsets. There is no way to return these results as a single resultset.